# MongoDB: Using match with input document variables

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Why do I have to use this code: `{ $match: { $expr: { <aggregation expression> } } }` to match a document using a document input variable as opposed to doing: `{ $match: { <query> } }` ?

For example:

```
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      let: { myvar: '$myInputDocVariable'},
      pipeline: [
        { $match:
            { $expr:
               { $and:
                  [
                    { $eq: [ "$varFromCommentDocument",  "$$myvar" ] },
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
        ],
      as: "returnedValue"
    }
```

The query above works fine but the query below does not work as expected. Why is this? Does this mean that if you are using input variables in a `$lookup` pipeline you have to use `$expr`? why is that?

```
    $lookup: {
      from: "comments",
      let: { myvar: '$myInputDocVariable'},
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { "$varFromCommentDocument", "$$myvar" } }
      ],
      as: "returnedValue"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that if you are using input variables in a $lookup
>   pipeline you have to use $expr

Yes correct, by default in filters i.e; in filter part of `.find()` or in `$match` aggregation stage you can't use an existing field in the document.

If at all if you need to use existing field's value in your query filter then you need to use aggregation pipeline, So in order to use aggregation pipeline in `.find()` or in `$match` you need to wrap your filter query with [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html#behavior). Same way to access local variables got created using `let` of `$lookup` filter in `$match` needs to be wrapped by `$expr`.

Let's consider below example :

**Sample Docs :**

```
[
  {
    "key": 1,
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "key": 2,
    "value": 4
  },
  {
    "key": 5,
    "value": 5
  }
]
```

**Query :**

```
 db.collection.find({ key: { $gt: 1 }, value: { $gt: 4 } })

    Or

 db.collection.aggregate([ { $match: { key: { $gt: 1 }, value: { $gt: 4 } } } ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7Ze3iPOdivj)

If you see the above query both input `1` & `4` are passed into query but it you check below query where you try to match `key` field == `value` field - it doesn't work :

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { $match: { key: { $eq: "$value" } } } ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m44YiEqFHo8)

Above as you're comparing two existing fields then you can't do that as it mean you're checking for docs with `key` field value as string `"$value"`. So to say it's not a string it's actually a reference to `value` field you need to use [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/index.html) aggregation operator rather than [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/index.html) query operator like below :

```
 db.collection.aggregate([ { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$key", "$value" ] } } } ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V_f6ANZkjr5)

Comment: Hi @whoami kindly check out this other [mongodb aggregation question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62878339/9953550). Thank you.

Comment: @YulePale: Sorry dude, unfortunately, I'm out on a vacation and not having laptop at this moment.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 3):

When you perform [uncorrelated sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) for `$lookup` operator:

- If you need to compare parent collection's `field` within `pipeline`, MongoDB cannot apply the standard query syntax (`field:value`) for `variable` / [Aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions). In this case, you need to use `$expr` operator.

Example:

```
{ $match:
  { $expr:
    { $and:[
      { $eq: [ "$varFromCommentDocument",  "$$myvar" ] },
    ]}
  }
}
```

- if it matches against "hard-coded" values, you don't need to use `$expr` operator.

Example:

```
$lookup: {
  from: "comments",
  pipeline: [
    { $match:{ 
      "key": "value",
      "key2": "value2"
    }}
  ],
  as: "returnedValue"
}
```