# Add a field to $lookup result in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to add a field to a lookup result with the node.js MongoDB driver. A user has two kinds of feeds 1. His or her own feeds and 2. Shared feeds. So i need to get both and then combine them.  This is my original query which works fine:

```
client.db('atlas').collection('users').aggregate([
    { $match: { user_id: userId } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'feeds',
        localField: "user_id",
        foreignField: "user_id",
        as: "feeds"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'shares',
        localField: 'email',
        foreignField: "share",
        as: "shares"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'feeds',
        localField: 'shares.feed_id',
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "shared_feeds"
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: { 'shared_feeds.share': true }
    },
    {
       $project: {
         user_id: 1,
         first_name: 1,
         last_name: 1,
         email: 1,
         feeds: { $concatArrays: [ '$feeds', '$shared_feeds' ] }
       }
    }
])
```

But I want to add a field to the second lookup on "feeds" so I tried using a pipeline like this:

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'feeds',
    let: { shareId: '$shares.feed_id' },
    pipeline: [
      { $match: { '_id': ObjectId('$$shareId') } }
    ],
    as: "shared_feeds"
  }
}
```

But I can't get the match to work with `ObjectId`. The variable doesn't appear to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Sample collections:
users:

```
[
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e970a1f797c08e70ce4e2f6"),
    "user_id" : "testuserid",
    "first_name" : "Jacopo",
    "last_name" : "Belbo",
    "email" : "test@test.com"
   }
]
```

feeds:

```
 [
  {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5f29b02318ecbf0083f01f1e"),
      "name" : "test csv",
      "user_id" : "auth0|5eac6faa1cc1ac0c147b5b16",
      "type" : "feed",
      "created_at" : ISODate("2020-08-04T18:59:47.640Z"),
      "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-08-04T18:59:47.640Z")
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f29b05d18ecbf0083f01f1f"),
    "name" : "typtap-small",
    "user_id" : "auth0|5f1b2da0e60194003d714680",
    "url" : "http://localstack:4572/atlas/usertes",
    "type" : "feed",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-08-04T19:00:45.886Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-08-04T19:00:45.886Z")
  }
]
```

shares:

```
[
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f29b07318ecbf0083f01f20"),
    "feed_id" : ObjectId("5f29b05d18ecbf0083f01f1f"),
    "share" : "test@test.com",
    "type" : "share",
    "recipient" : "email",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2020-08-04T19:01:07.668Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-08-04T19:01:07.668Z")
}
]
```

Comment: Your schema looks poor if you are doing that many lookups

Comment: If `shares.feed_id` already contains an ObjectId you can just use `'_id': '$$shareId'`

Comment: It appears that it's that shareId is an array so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `let: { shareId: '$shares.feed_id' },` your are passing an `ObjectId` to `shareId`. So you can't wrap with `ObjectId()` in `match` stage. When you use pipeline inside a lookup for multiple conditions Just use `$expr`

```
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: [
            "$$shareId",
            "$_id"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

**Update 1.**

when you use pipeline inside `$lookup`, you need to use `$expr`, Refer [$expr in lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup). Once you get the out put, you will have an array, so `$unwind` it and do the join. Then group it to avoid duplicates.

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JOKKv1rKCiy)

**Update 2**

The mongo script

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      user_id: "testuserid"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "feeds",
      localField: "user_id",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "feeds"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "shares",
      localField: "email",
      foreignField: "share",
      as: "shares"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$shares",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "feeds",
      let: {
        shareId: "$shares.feed_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$shareId",
                "$_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "shared_feeds"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      user_id: {
        $first: "$user_id"
      },
      first_name: {
        $first: "$first_name"
      },
      last_name: {
        $first: "$last_name"
      },
      email: {
        $first: "$email"
      },
      feeds: {
        $first: "$feeds"
      },
      shares: {
        $addToSet: "$shares"
      },
      shared_feeds: {
        $addToSet: "$shared_feeds"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      shared_feeds: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$shared_feeds",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "shared_feeds.share": true
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      user_id: 1,
      first_name: 1,
      last_name: 1,
      email: 1,
      feeds: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$feeds",
          "$shared_feeds"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This doesn't return any results.

Comment: Please add some sample data

Comment: I added the data

Comment: Works great. Thanks.

Comment: @varman you can update your answer with right syntax for this `{ $match: { '_id': '$$shareId' } }` from your playground link, because might be after some days playground link will be expire.

Comment: Sure I will update, Are you sure the like will be expired after few days? O.o

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) with `$eq` in match condition, because without expression it will not match reference fields, there is one example in [MongoDB Lookup with Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup),

- here need to use `$_id` instead of `_id`, because expression will not find field without `$` and `$eq` will not match condition,

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'feeds',
    let: { shareId: '$shares.feed_id' },
    pipeline: [
      { 
        $match: { 
          $expr: {
            $eq: ['$$shareId', '$_id'] 
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "shared_feeds"
  }
}
```

I am not sure what the type of this `shares.feed_id` field, if both the collection have different type, either one is in string or one is in object id then you can use [toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/),

You can convert string to object id like this,

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'feeds',
    let: { shareId: '$shares.feed_id' },
    pipeline: [
      { 
        $match: { 
          $expr: {
            $eq: [
              { '$toObjectId': '$$shareId' }, 
              '$_id'
            ] 
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    as: "shared_feeds"
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: "Unsupported conversion from array to objectId".  I tried $map and it just didn't didn't match anything. feed_id is an ObjectId.

Comment: It will helpful if you add some sample data.