# How to convert sql query with exist into mongodb query

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two documents on mongodb, these are **percentages** and **items**. I'm good at SQL, I can write PLSql query as follows but i can not convert to mongodb query. Because my mongodb level of knowledge is at the beginning. 
Actually I know I have to use $gt for the and condition. But I don't know how I can say not exists or union keyword for mongodb. How can I write mongodb query? which keywords should i search for?

```
select p.*, "to_top" as list 
  from percentages p
 where p.percentage > 5
   and p.updatetime > sysdate - 1/24
   and not exists (select 1
                     from items i
                    where i.id = p.p_id
                      and i.seller = p.seller)
 order by p.percentage desc
union
select p2.*, "to_bottom" as list 
  from percentages p2
 where p2.percentage > 5
   and p2.updatetime > sysdate - 1/24
   and exists (select 1
                  from items i2
                 where i2.id = p2.p_id
                   and i2.seller = p2.seller)
order by p2.percentage desc
```

Comment: You does your collection looks like and what is it's corresponding output that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `UNION` for MongoDB. Luckely, each query is performed on the same collection and have very close condition, so we can implement "Mongo way" query.

### Explanation

Normally, alsmost all complex SQL queries are done with the [MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) framework.

1. We filter document by `percentage` / `updatetime`. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61949348/3710490) why we need to use `$expr`
2. SQL JOIN / Subquery is done with the [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) operator.
3. SQL `SYSDATE` in MongoDB way can be `NOW` or `CLUSTER_TIME` [variable](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables).

---

```
db.percentages.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      percentage: { $gt: 5 },
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          "$updatetime",
          {
            $subtract: [
              ISODate("2020-06-14T13:00:00Z"), //Change to $$NOW or $$CLUSTER_TIME
              3600000
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "items",
      let: {
        p_id: "$p_id",
        seller: "$seller"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [ "$$p_id", "$id"]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [ "$$seller", "$seller"]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      as: "items"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      list: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [{$size: "$items"}, 0]
          },
          "$to_top",
          "$to_bottom"
        ]
      },
      items: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { percentage: -1 }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mteuno4EhMT)

**Note:** The MongoDB aggregation has the [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) operator that allows to perform different queries on the same collection.

SCHEMA:

```
db.percentages.aggregate([
  {$facet:{
    q1:[...],
    q2:[...],
  }},
  //We apply "UNION" the result documents for each pipeline into single array
  {$project:{
    data:{$concatArrays:["$q1","$q2"]}
  }},
  //Flatten array into single object
  {$unwind:"$data"}
  //Replace top-level document
  {$replaceWith:"$data"}
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E9Kzx284UCG)

Answer (score 0):

why you don't import your mangoDB data into oracle and use sql(that is more easy and powerful than mango.)

Comment: Yep, oracle more easy for me but I thought mongodb would produce faster results. my  nodejs app has to be faster. Also i wanted to learn mongo.